# Поймать момент когда игра проигрывает звук имея его wav файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, windows-8, wav

Существует конкретный файл в формате .wav. 

**Вопрос:** можно ли с устройства воспроизведения считать этот звук *(как я понимаю, он должен быть в виде последовательности байтов)*, если он будет проигран в другом приложении. 
И если можно, то как?

Если это важно: OS Windows 8.1, Python 3.6.4

Моя задача чем-то напоминает Shazam.

Comment: По умолчанию, нет, кажется, рутинг аудиопотока между приложениями в винде не совсем тривиален. Если только совсем опосредованно, слушать микрофон и ловить звук.

Comment: к примеру: в игре воспроизводится звук, и у меня этот звук есть на компьютере в виде .wav файла. И я хочу делать что-либо, если я этот звук "отловил".

Comment: Если питон кушает COM-объекты, для захвата звука можно использовать WASAPI Loopback https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: да, т.е. мне нужно поймать звук из игры, и я точно знаю, какой именно звук в игре будет воспроизведен ибо у меня есть его .wav файл

Comment: нашел вот такой пример: https://habr.com/post/335580/ там pyaudio используется для отслеживания звука, но не какого-то конкретного, а просто преодолевшего отметку громкости.

Comment: p.s. я тут осознал, что моя задача чем-то напоминает Shazam

Comment: если прямо указанный wav игра проигрывает, то можно просто отследить, когда приложение читает этот файл.

Comment: Вряд ли игра будет каждый раз читать его с диска, в первый раз прочитает, потом будет брать из памяти. Причём, не факт, что прочитает непосредственно перед воспроизведением, скроее всего, при загрузке уровня. Да и, скорее всего, звук будет проигрываться не один, на него наложится фоновая музыка и другие звуки. Так что, если подходить с этой стороны, задача превращается в написание своего Shazam. В игре точно нет своей скриптовой системы, позволяющей более гуманным способом отследить событие?

Comment: к сожалению, гуманного способа нет